# Read textfile line by line and scan from buffert - C

Tags: c, file, text-files, fgets, scanf

I have made a program which handles and stores records of movies in a library. This is how my library looks like when I print it out to a file.
So basicly my problem is to read this file and save those columns in my struct of variables and dynamically increase the size of the struct for every entry.
Right now I have a while loop reading line by line into a buffert and I am then trying to scan the values from the buffert.
I know the format of the spacings in between the columns if that helps.(No it's not tabs, would that help?)
Else i thought about once it finds "two spaces" it could parse onto the next one...
What I'm looking for is something like this:

("%s %d %d %d %s %d", name, &id, &qty, &price, genre, &year)

This is how the textfile looks like: "test.txt" (UPDATED version below)

```
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
NAME                                          ID    QTY   PRICE GENRE      YEAR
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
THE SHAWSHANK REDEMPTION                      1     25    99    Crime      1994
THE GODFATHER                                 2     65    199   Crime      1972
PULP FICTION                                  3     265   99    Drama      1994
THE LORD OF THE RINGS                         4     1024  199   Action     2003
THE DARK KNIGHT                               5     99    99    Action     2008
```

And this is how my code looks like:

```
void read_from_file(struct movies *movie)
{
    FILE *fp;
    char buffer[1024];
    int line_num = 0;
    int index = 0;

    fp = fopen("test.txt", "r");

    if ( fp == NULL )
    {
        printf("Error opening file!\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    fgets(buffer, 1024, fp); fgets(buffer, 1024, fp); fgets(buffer, 1024, fp); // Skip 3 first lines (header)

    while(fgets(buffer, 1024, fp) != NULL) // read one line to buffer at a time
    {  
        printf("%s", buffer); //DEBUG 

        // Trying here to read only the names which i know should be no longer than 40chars. first row goes well, then it's messed up
        sscanf(buffer, "%40[^\0]" , movie[index].name);

        index++;
    }

    fclose(fp);
    getch();
}
```

Update: I changed the format of the storage file to the following:

```
THE SHAWSHANK REDEMPTION,1,25,99,Crime,1994
THE GODFATHER,2,75,199,Crime,1972
PULP FICTION,3,512,99,Drama,2000
THE LORD OF THE RINGS,4,1024,199,Action,2003
THE DARK KNIGHT,5,99,99,Action,2008
```

Comment: _"The Godfather: Part II"_ should be at [3rd](http://www.imdb.com/chart/top?ref_=nv_ch_250_4) :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main problem is that there is no single char delimiter.  So process the first 45 char;

```
while(fgets(buffer, sizeof buffer, fp) != NULL) {
  printf("%s", buffer); //DEBUG
  if (strlen(buf < 80)) {
    handle_short_line_error();
  }
  size_t len;
  for (len = 45; len > 0; len--) {
    if (!isspace(buf[len-1])) {
      break;
    }
  }
  if (!IsAGoodLength(len)) {
    handle_format_error();
  }
  memcpy(movie[index].name, buf, len);
  movie[index].name[len] = '\0';
  if (5 != sscanf(&buffer[45], "%d%d%d%9s%d", &id, &qty, &price, genre, &year)) {
    handle_format_error();
  }
  // Use other fields scanned
  index++;
}
```

Comment: I changed the look of the txtfile.
`THE SHAWSHANK REDEMPTION:1:25:99:Crime:1994`
That should make it easier with `:` as delimiter?

Comment: @Zn3, consider `,` as that is a very common delimiter.  In any case, chances are _some_ movie title will use whatever delimiter you select and you have to deal with [long names](http://www.imdb.com/list/mfrLWtwlf3U/).

Comment: `,` is fine and the name of movies is max 40chars. If user inputs more than that it's just stripped away so it's fine

Comment: I managed to solve it.
I used something like this as format:
`sscanf(buffer, "%[^:]:%d:%d:%d:%[^:]:%d);` and it worked fine